# Highmaps: Wrap fillSetter for colorAxis

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highmaps to draw a world map with a basic colorAxis from 0 - 100:

```
colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    minColor : '#ffff00',
    maxColor : '#ff0000'
}
```

So far so easy. Now I like to add diagonal hatching for some of the countries. I stumbled across the following plugin:

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill

This works, but only when you hover over a country (which is somehow consistent, because colorAxis is global for the entire map). So I tried to wrap fillSetter:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.SVGElement.prototype, 'fillSetter', function (proceed, color, prop, elem)
```

My questions:

1. Is this the way to go?
2. How I can determine from given elem if it is the Path for the country (I noticed, that Highmaps adds a class `highmaps-key-` to each of the Path elements). Is there an easier solution?
3. Can I somehow access the series during this process? I would need to check my data to determine if the country should be filled with a solid color or with diagonal hatching

Thanks a lot in advance for all hints!

Comment: How are you applying the pattern?  I tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7AdMK/ and it seems to work.

Comment: I think the problem is `colorAxis` and patterns. The solution will be to not setting value for countries, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7AdMK/2/ - of course, if you want tooltip to display value, then set value as some custom property.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Yes, combining `colorAxis` and patterns is the problem. I cannot use colorAxis for individual series, right? Is there at least a way to access the series data within a wrap callback?

Comment: Use callback: `$('#x').highcharts(options, function(chart) { .. })`. But I'm not sure why do you need callback? You can preprocess your data before creating chart, right?

Comment: Hi Pawel. Thanks for the hint, how to access the chart itself. I ended up using a different approach though (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the inputs. I ended up with a different approach. Instead of wrapping the rendering itself, I wrapped the color calculation of `colorAxis`. Something like this:

```
 Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.ColorAxis.prototype, 'toColor', function (proceed, value, point) {
    var color = proceed.call(this, value, point);
    if(point.isSpecial) {
        color = color.replace("rgb", "rgba");
        color = color.replace(")", ", 0.3)");
    }
    return color;
});
```

For our use-case, rendering the special points (countries) with reduced opacity is enough. This approach has another advantage: it isn't necessary to handle SVG and VML rendering separately. If you wrap fillSetter, this would have been necessary, if you want to support IE8 (see source code of the pattern fill plugin). YMMV.